# Generate json array of directory in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to write a Jekyll plugin which generates an array of pages in a directory in a json file. So for a directory which contains foo.html and a sub-directory foo containing bar.html, it'd generate "foo, /foo/bar". I'm completely new to Ruby, does somone have any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use globs and wildcards with [Ruby's Dir class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html). You could get an array of .html files recursively from the current directory, using something along the lines of `files = Dir['./**/*.html']`.

To generate JSON, you'd want to first ensure that the person using your plugin has access to a JSON library (`require 'json'`) and then use the `#to_json` helper method on your files array: `files.to_json`